# in select command multiple where clause indentation error

Tags: python

```
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM developers_info WHERE field = 'runtime' AND experience = 3 ")
  data2 = cur.fetchall()
```

> File "project_part2.py", line 55     cur.execute("SELECT name FROM >developers_info WHERE field = 'runtime' AND experience = 3 ")       ^
>
> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Paste the this line and a few before it using the code markdown. This will show your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not indented properly. 
Either not indented at same level as the previous line
OR
previous line has a `:` and this line should be indented further.